# Android App fails to connect to the internet

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an app which uses Android API 28, but I am having an issue with the app not always recognizing that the phone has internet access. However, other apps on the phone is working. The function I used to check the internet connection is:

```
fun checkInternetConnection(): Boolean
{
        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.isDefaultNetworkActive
        return networkInfo
}
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
fun hasNetwork(context: Context): Boolean {
            var isConnected: Boolean = false
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected)
                isConnected = true
            return isConnected
        }
```

Also give permission in menifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you give permissions in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```